# QT 5.4 QPrinterInfo::printerName returns blanks

Tags: c++, linux, qt, printing

I am trying to instantiate a printer without using QPrintDialog as our GUI is QML where QPrintDialog does not exist (we are creating a printer selection dialog in QML). I am calling two invokable C++ functions 1) one function retrieves a list of valid printers and passes that back to QML, and 2) second function instantiate a printer name that was selected by the user in QML and then prints to a painter. I am using Ubuntu Linux (32) with Qt5.4.0. One interesting issue I uncovered is that when I use QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames() a valid list of printer names is found. When I get a list of QPrinterInfo object via using static function QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters(), then traverse the list and display the names in printerName, an empty string is returned. The documentation says that this should be a unique ID for the printer, not an empty string?????

Here's is a extract which demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinterInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Printer names via availablePrinterNames method";
    QStringList name_list = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames();
    foreach ( QString name, name_list)
        qDebug() << name;

    qDebug() << "\nPrinter names via availablePrinters method";
    QList<QPrinterInfo> info_list = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters();
    foreach ( QPrinterInfo info, info_list )
        qDebug() << info.printerName();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have not tried this with earlier versions of QT or the Windows version. Does anyone have any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Just ran this console app in the Windows version of 5.4.0 and it works perfectly. Also there is a QT += core printsupport in the project file for both linux and windows project files.

Comment: FWIW, I get identical list for both functions. Running Gentoo amd64, qt-5.4.0. Compiled with `g++ runme.cpp -I /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/ -I /usr/include/qt5/ -fPIC -lQt5Core -lQt5PrintSupport`

Comment: Innocent Bystander: Thxs for running on your system. Hmmm, could be my environment. One detail I forgot to mention is that I am running inside a VMWare VM for Ubuntu 14.10, could be my Linux environment so I will try on some other Linux machines running natively (not in a VM).

Comment: I run this test program on 2 linux machines that are not running in a VM - works correctly so there is definitely an issue with my VM or the package setup in the VM.

Comment: SportPilot, seems so. FWIW, I would try to reinstall `cups` and related `Qt` libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In short: The reason for the issue is that CUPS supports driverless printers ([info](https://wiki.debian.org/DriverlessPrinting)), and Qt does not.

Qt uses CUPS API to return the list of printers in system (availablePrinterNames) without checking, but when it constructs QPrinterInfo, it checks if the printer has a PPD driver. If not, the printer is considered invalid, and Qt returns empty name for it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it worked for me. First you should add windowsprintersupport.dll to your project.

```
int count = 0;
QList<QPrinterInfo> info_list = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters();
    foreach ( QPrinterInfo info, info_list )
    {
        count++;
        qDebug()<< "Printer_"<< count<< ": " << info.printerName() << "State: " << info.state();

        if(info.printerName() == "YOUR_PRINTER_NAME")
        {
            if (info.state() == 0)
                qDebug()<< "Printer Idle";
            else if (info.state() == 1)
                qDebug()<< "Printer Active";
            else if (info.state() == 2)
                qDebug()<< "Printer Aborted";
            else if (info.state() == 3)
                qDebug()<< "Printer Error";
            else
                qDebug()<< "Printer Undefined Error";
        }

    }
```